# Custom attribute, show it about everywhere?

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, attributes, custom-options

I have a Donut webshop and would like to add a custom attribute and to show this attribute at many places.

I want to add the text: "Box à 8 peeces" or "Box à 12 peeces" etc. underneath the title.

How can I do this the easiest way? There would be many files to be changed and I wonder if there is a better way to do this?

At the moment I search the phtml files and add the attribute by using:

```
<?php echo $_product->getAttributename() ?>
```

Before going on with this I would like to know if there are better ways to do this. I'm a designer and not a great coder. Any tips are very welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only place in the Magento frontend where Magento automatically displays a custom product attribute is the `catalog/product/view/attributes.phtml` template.

In order for an attribute to be displayed there, it needs to fulfill the following prerequisites:

- It must be part of the products attribute set
- The attributes `is_visible_on_front` property must be set to `1`. This can be done in the manage attributes page in the Magento backend.
- The attribute value for that product must be a string (and not `''`)

If you want to output the attribute values anywhere else, you will have to modify the templates where you want to display the attribute manually.

If you want to display product attributes in the **cart** or the **checkout**, be aware that you are working with quote items there, not product instances.
To get the corresponding product instance you can use `$_item->getProduct()`, and then fetch your attribute value from there.

If your attribute value isn't available on those product instances, add it to the configuration XML under `global/sales/quote/item/product_attributes`.
Here is the list the sales module loads by default:

```
<global>
    <sales>
        <quote>
            <item>
                <product_attributes>
                    <sku/>
                    <type_id/>
                    <name/>
                    <status/>
                    <visibility/>
                    <price/>
                    <weight/>
                    <url_path/>
                    <url_key/>
                    <thumbnail/>
                    <small_image/>
                    <tax_class_id/>
                    <special_from_date/>
                    <special_to_date/>
                    <special_price/>
                    <cost/>
                    <is_recurring/>
                    <recurring_profile/>
                    <gift_message_available/>
                    <msrp_enabled/>
                    <msrp/>
                    <msrp_display_actual_price_type/>
                </product_attributes>
            </item>
        </quote>
    </sales>
</global>
```

Comment: I'm trying to show my attribute on the template/checkout/cart/item/default.phtm Doesn't work when I use one of these two: 1: <?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_item->getData('aantal')); ?>
2: <?php echo $_product->getAantal() ?>

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: thanks allot, I will have a look asap if I mange to get that working!